# Coulomb in Voltage formula is confusing me. What to do?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, voltage

[image]

To make my question clear I've added a picture above which I drew myself which shows 2 scenarios where the only difference is the sign of the charge. Essentially we have an electric field produced by a positive electric plate and it's effects of repulsion/attraction on a positive/negative charge.

Now, to calculate the voltage I simply use the Voltage=Delta Energy/Coulomb formula. I use the Lower potential energy point as the reference point.In the positive charge scenario it gives me +12V (This makes sense as it's at a higher potential energy point relative to the reference point). Whereas the negative charge scenario it gives me -12V (which doesn't make sense since it's at a higher potential energy point RELATIVE to the reference point so it should also be positive).

Do we just take the absolute value of the charge when dealing with Voltage? I hope I explained it well enough. I'd really appreciate some help.   (The numbers are arbitrary by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential difference between two points is equal to the work done by an external force in moving unit **positive** charge between those two points.

So for your top diagram with the positive charge starting on the left, potential $V$, and moving to the right, potential $0$, the work done by an external force on a charge of $+1\,\rm C$ is $-12\rm \,J$.

So the change in potential $0-V=-12 \Rightarrow V=+12$.

In your second diagram moving the negative charge from right to left requires the external force to do $-12\,\rm J$ of work which would be $+12\,\rm J$ of work if the charge were positive.

So the change in potential $V-0=+12 \Rightarrow V=+12$ as before.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much

Comment: Isn't there a *drop* in potential in both cases?

Comment: @sammygerbil Indeed there is a drop as reflected in the term $0-V$ which is negative if $V$ is a positive quantity.